# What is the cause of "Cannot read property 'hasOwnProperty' of undefined" in this code snippet?

Tags: javascript, node.js, lodash

I've seen the error in the title come through in our logs several times. It's being thrown from the last line in the code snippet below. From my research, this error is thrown when attempting to access a variable that doesn't exist; however, I'm under the impression that I'm checking for that very existence on line 1.

```
if(rental_application.rental_history && rental_application.rental_history.length > 0) {
    candidate.rental_history = [];
        _.each(rental_application.rental_history, function(rental) {
```

What could be the issue here?

Comment: `rental_application.rental_history` is, or contains undefined values that cant be looked up with `hasOwnProperty` internally in LoDash `_.each` method

Comment: you can use the real [].forEach, which skips undefined values safely (uses `in` instead of `hasOwnProperty`)

Comment: You could also use the underscore _.has() function to replace your first line... _.has({"three" : 5 }, "three");

Comment: @adeneo Why would the first line of code successfully pass the check? Do I have a misconception as to what it's really checking? Or is it possible that I have a null element somewhere in the array somewhere?

Comment: You should probably `console.log( rental_application.rental_history )` and see what it contains

Comment: @adeneo The logged stacktrace was a few lines off from the real issue (I'm performing an unsafe property access); however, following your advice and just doing a console log made it obvious. 

Anyway, technically your first comment is a correct answer. Feel free to submit it as one.